# Texture looks messed up when I change the mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, transforms

When I change my mesh, The texture on the mesh doesn't look good. Here is an example. I have a cube with a texture:
[image: Cube with the texture]

It looks ok now but when I scale one of the edges, the texture becomes messed up:
[[image: Messed up Texture2]

As you can see it doesn't look how it's supposed to. this is how I believe It should look (Made it in photoshop):
[image: Correct form]

Why does that distortion happen? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because each quad is actually made of 2 triangles, so if you twist a face it will also move the virtual edge that separates the two triangles and therefore create this distortion:

[image]

The only way to avoid that is to subdivide your mesh enough so it's not noticeable:

[image]